# AWS SNS publish only works locally, but not from lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, serverless

This is the code that runs successfully on local to send sms

```
const snsParams = {
  Message: "Hello World",
  PhoneNumber: normalizedPhoneNumber,
};

const sms = messager.publish(snsParams).promise();

sms.then(data => {
  console.log('Success!', data);
}).catch(err => {
  console.log('Error!', err);
});
```

However, this does not fire from my deployed lambda.

My serverless.yml contains the necessary iamRoleStatements like this

```
iamRoleStatements:
- Effect: Allow
  Action:
    - dynamodb:DescribeTable
    - dynamodb:Query
    - dynamodb:Scan
    - dynamodb:BatchGetItem
    - dynamodb:BatchWriteItem
    - dynamodb:GetItem
    - dynamodb:PutItem
    - dynamodb:UpdateItem
    - dynamodb:DeleteItem
  Resource:
    - arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-1:*:table/${app-name}-${self:custom.stage}
    - arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-1:*:table/${app-name}-${self:custom.stage}/*
- Effect: Allow
  Action:
    - sns:*
  Resource: "*"
```

I've also checked from the IAM Management console to see that SNS is included in my lambda role

[image]

How can I make this work? What am I missing?

Comment: Could you share your lambda code please, and some logging with the response you get for sending, to confirm that your lambda isn't returning before the SNS is sent &c.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem could be in promises, because the line
`messager.publish(snsParams).promise();` creates only a promise and there is no waiting when the promise is executed.

You can change your code so:

```
exports.handler = async function(event) {
  ...
  const snsParams = {
    Message: "Hello World",
    PhoneNumber: normalizedPhoneNumber,
  };
  try {
    const sms = await messager.publish(snsParams).promise();
    console.log('Success!', sms);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Error!', err);
  }
}
```